# Differential equation: with initial value problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any solution to this initial value problem.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y'}$$

with initial values $y(0)=-6$

i have tried and got answers like $$y=\frac{x^2}{2}-6$$

and like $$y=\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}-6$$
but they both doesn't satisfy the initial equation.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why do you say $y=\dfrac{2x^{3/2}}3-6$ doesn't satisfy the initial equation?

Comment: Your differential equation becomes $(y')^2=x$ or $y'=\sqrt{x}$ $$\int dy=\int \sqrt{x}dx\implies y=\frac23x^{3/2}+C$$ setting $y(0)=-6$, you get $$y=\frac23x^{3/2}-6$$ Therefore your second answer is correct & duly satisfies given condition

Answer (score 1):

The second absolutely satisfies the differential equation. Notice that $y' = \sqrt x$. Then is it not true that

$$\sqrt x = \frac{x}{\sqrt x}?$$

The left-hand side and denominator are both $dy/dx = y'$, and the numerator is the $x$ from the equation. Everything seems fine. It even satisfies the initial condition.

My only guess for why your answer might be considered "wrong" is that

$$y = - \frac 2 3 x^{3/2} - 6$$

also works (the negative will cancel out).

Comment: Thanks,,I was doing wrong while putting the values of y back in the equation.